# Go equivalents for the Java Ecosystem

Tags: java, go

I'm trying to start using Go (golang) for a project and coming from a java background, I was curious if there are equivalents for the following in the Go ecosystem:

1. IDE (Looks like both Eclipse and IDEA have Go plugins). The Eclipse Go plugin was not as refined as the Java one when I looked last.
2. Is there a Maven equivalent for dependency management?
3. Jenkins/Luntbuild equivalent for continuous integration?
4. Any well known libraries like Guava?

Any other tips/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Sublime Text 2 or Vim
2. Go dependencies are determined by your import statements which means whatever your code imports is what it depends on
3. Travis CI
4. you can refer to the [golang homepage](http://golang.org/doc/)

Comment: Emacs + gocode also works very well, especially with the new Emacs mode in Go tip. There's optional support for on-the-fly compilation and error highlighting using goflymake.

Comment: I highly recommend [GoSublime](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime) for Sublime Text 2. It signifcantly speeds up development with features like code completion and context aware snippets ([and many more](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime#features)). Also, take a look at [GoDoc](http://godoc.org/).